# Visual Studio 2013 cannot convert VS 2012 C++ Projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

All my C++ Visual Studio 2012 projects cannot be upgraded by VS 2013 Professional Update 2, microsoft tells that you also need to have VS2012 installed in order to open VS 2012 projects.

The problem is that I have installed VS2012 and still get the same error.

after each project name in VS 2013 I have (Project incompatible), I want to convert the projects to VS2013 because I don't want to use VS2012 anymore.

```
Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.

No changes required
These projects can be opened in Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without changing them.
```

and this is the error in **migration report**

```
The application which this project type is based on was not found.
```

I found somewhere on a forum that if you install VS 2012 SDK it should work, but the VS2012 SDK cannot be installed because it cannot find Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Which edition of Visual Studio 2013 are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio Professional Update 2

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting? Is it possible you can't overwrite the project files?

Comment: The build option is not available, because the project is incompatible. No, the files can be overwritten.

Comment: When I open the project for the first time it tries to migrate the project, but I get an error, see the updated question..

Comment: Open the .vcxproj file with a text editor, Notepad is fine.  Google the `<ProjectGuid>` you find.  Post it in your question if that doesn't help.  If it is common one then do consider that the VS2013 install did not go well.

Comment: No, it did not find anything on google, because the project GUID should be unique to your project.